# How to run requests.get asynchronously in Python 3 using asyncio?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create simple web monitoring script which sends GET request to urls in list periodically and asynchronously. Here is my request function:

```
def request(url,timeout=10):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url,timeout=timeout)
        response_time = response.elapsed.total_seconds()
        if response.status_code in (404,500):
            response.raise_for_status()
        html_response = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_response,'lxml')
        # process page here
        logger.info("OK {}. Response time: {} seconds".format(url,response_time))
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        logger.error('Connection error. {} is down. Response time: {} seconds'.format(url,response_time))
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        logger.error('Timeout. {} not responding. Response time: {} seconds'.format(url,response_time))
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        logger.error('HTTP Error. {} returned status code {}. Response time: {} seconds'.format(url,response.status_code, response_time))
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        logger.error('Too many redirects for {}. Response time: {} seconds'.format(url,response_time))
    except:
        logger.error('Content requirement not found for {}. Response time: {} seconds'.format(url,response_time))
```

And here where I call this function for all urls:

```
def async_requests(delay,urls):
    for url in urls:
        async_task = make_async(request,delay,url,10)
        loop.call_soon(delay,async_task)
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

`delay` argument is interval for loop which describes how often function needs to be executed. In order to loop `request` I created something like this:

```
def make_async(func,delay,*args,**kwargs):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        loop.call_soon(delay, wrapper)

    return wrapper
```

every time I execute `async_requests` I get this error for each url:

```
Exception in callback 1.0(<function mak...x7f1d48dd1730>)
handle: <Handle 1.0(<function mak...x7f1d48dd1730>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 125, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Also `request` functions for each urls are not being executed periodically as intended. Also my print function which goes after `async_requests` is not executed either:

```
async_requests(args.delay,urls)
print("Starting...")
```

I understand that I'm doing something wrong in code but I can't figure how to solve this problem. I'm beginner in python and not very experienced with asyncio. 
Summarizing what I want to achive:

- Run asynchronously and periodcally `request` for particular url without blocking main thread.
- Run `async_requests` asynchronously so I could launch a simple http server
  for example in same thread.

Comment: `call_soon` doesn’t work the way you’re using it. It takes a callback as its first argument. Everything that follows is an argument passed to the callback. The callback is called as soon as control returns back to the event loop. What you’re looking for is `call_later`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
except:
```

It'll catch also service exceptions line `KeyboardInterrupt` or `StopIteration`. Never do such thing. Instead write:

```
except Exception:
```

---

> How to run requests.get asynchronously in Python 3 using asyncio?

`requests.get` is blocking by nature.

You should either find async alternative for requests like `aiohttp` module:

```
async def get(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.text()
```

or run `requests.get` in separate thread and await this thread asynchronicity using `loop.run_in_executor`:

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(2)

async def get(url):
    response = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, requests.get, url)
    return response.text
```