# python asynchronous requests

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio

So I have a list of image url's that I want to iterate over with the requests library and download all the images to a directory.

```
def get_image(url, image_name):
    path = pathlib.Path('/path/to/some/directory')
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open('{}/{}.png'.format(path, image_name), 'wb') as file:
        for block in response.iter_content(1024):
            file.write(block)

for url in urls:
    get_image(url, image_name)
```

Now, is there no way I could create a decorator to make a function a callback to run once a response is returned for a specific asynchronous request?

Comment: `requests` is not an asynchronous library, it is not compatible with asyncio at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want multiple concurrent `requests` + callbacks you can use module like [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests#grequests-asynchronous-requests). It has nothing to do with `asyncio`.

`asyncio` - is all about to avoid using of callbacks (to avoid [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)) and make writing of asynchronous code as easy as synchronous one.

If you decide to try `asyncio` you should either use `aiohttp` [client](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request) instead of `requests` (this is preferred way) or run `requests` in thread pool managed by asyncio. Example of both ways can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210102/1113207).

Answer (score 0):

The recommended grequests now recommends:

> Note: You should probably use requests-threads or [requests-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) instead.

Example usage of requests-futures:

> ```
> from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession
>
> session = FuturesSession()
> # first request is started in background
> future_one = session.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
> # second requests is started immediately
> future_two = session.get('http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar')
> # wait for the first request to complete, if it hasn't already
> response_one = future_one.result()
> print('response one status: {0}'.format(response_one.status_code))
> print(response_one.content)
> # wait for the second request to complete, if it hasn't already
> response_two = future_two.result()
> print('response two status: {0}'.format(response_two.status_code))
> print(response_two.content)
> ```