# Await a method and assign a variable to the returned value with asyncio?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm using asyncio with requests to try to make a core module asynchronous program. I've ran into a difficulty when trying to do something like this

```
import asyncio
import requests
async def main():
    await r = requests.get(URL)
```

What I thought this would do is wait for the get request to finish, then take the return value and put it in r, but this error happens

```
  File "prog.py", line 20
    await r = requests.get(URL)
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to await expression
```

r = await requests.get(URL) doesn't seem to work either, giving

```
prog.py:31: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'coroutine' was never awaited
  coroutine(args)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### How to use `await`?

`await` can be used only to await `coroutine` - special object returned by calling function defined with `async def`:

```
import asyncio


async def test():
    return True


async def main():

    # test() returns coroutine:
    coro = test()
    print(coro)  # <coroutine object test at ...>


    # we can await for coroutine to get result:
    res = await coro    
    print(res)  # True



if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Read also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) about using `asyncio`.

### Why `await requests.get(URL)` doesn't work?

Because `requests.get` is not a coroutine (it's not defined with `async def`), it's regular function by nature.

If you want to make request asynchronously you should either use special async module like `aiohttp` for this or wrap `requests` into coroutine using threads. See code snippets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210102/1113207) for both examples.